# Creating an image upload input field

Tags: 8, media

I'm creating a image upload input field in blockForm which will output to Twig later. But got stuck due to some stuff.

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
        $form['image_file'] = [
            '#type' => 'managed_file',
            '#title' => $this->t('Upload Your Image'),
            '#default_value' => (isset($this->configuration['image_file']) ? $this->configuration['image_file'] : ""),
            '#weight' => '1',
            '#upload_location' => 'public://',
            '#upload_validators' => [
                'file_validate_extensions' => ['gif png jpg jpeg'],
            ],
        ];

       return $form;
    }
```

First thing is the `'#upload_location'`, there are a lot of different answer online and the only difference is the path after `public://`, so I want to know what should I actually deal with it.

Second is the `use`, is there something missing or it is enough for achieve my goal.

The code I have now:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph;
```

Hope someone can answer and help. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you could use something like this `'#type' => 'file'`

```
  $form['image_file']=array(  
    '#type' => 'file',
   '#title' => t('Upload YourImage'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif'),),

        );
return $form;
```